# Which is better for code update among multiple systems - rsync or git?

Tags: git, rsync

As the title suggests, which is a better option to update code - between rsync and git, when one is working on several systems, some of them are remote, local and one is the central repository for the entire team. Some constraints are that these directories have some system-dependent files which we don't want to share with other users/systems.

For example, it is developers working on the code, but in different sections of the code. So for example, I might be working using 3 machines, one of them is an HPC where I only simulate my development version of code but don't modify the code, and another developer is working using 2 machines, and then there is the central repository hosted at gitlab.

I know most developers would choose git, but which properties of git make it better than rsync here? If you choose otherwise, then why that too?

Comment: This question is too broad and subjective. Without knowing the exact situation, you cannot expect reasonable answers. Ideally describe your constraints with a little more detail, and tell us what you've tried so far, or where you see problems. Also, it'd be good to know if there are mostly *humans* working on the code and editing it from different places, or just mostly machines pulling code changes from a central place. (If it's humans and you need conflict resolutions, of course go with Git. In most other cases... my opinion is: still go with Git.)

Comment: @slhck details added :)

Comment: Thanks. There might be some bias in your approach if you are considering `rsync` at all, in the situation you describe. The combination of Git and GitLab offers everything you need here, and the benefits of Git are quite obvious in this situation. What I don't understand is: what exactly would you consider  rsync for? Just deploying the code to the test machines? Because you're using Git/GitLab anyway. Have a look at deploy tokens if you want read-only access. There is no good reason to go for `rsync`, particularly if the code is already in a repo.

Comment: I see, but does it affect if we set git between two machines', say A and B, for directory _a_ and then try to set git between machines B and C, for the same directory _a_? We want to be able to access the changes made in A from B and access changes made in B from C, but not the other way round.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set Git for a directory between machines". Particularly how you describe accessing changes. If changes are made in a Git repo, they are accessible to anyone who can clone that repo. What you *can* define is who can push to that repo. Perhaps you need to incldue a small diagram in your question that better explains what you're after.